# Web Intelligence : double column parameter

Tags: business-objects, webi

I try to do something like that (it's a count of order between 2 price depending months) :

[image: do]

It works until I drag and drop my column "100-500" next to "0-100":

[image]

Is there a tips to do what I want ?

I work on Web Intelligence 4.2 Support Pack 4 Compilation : 14.2.4.2410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do that. I used my months two times in my table for my two differents interval.

[image]

And then I fusionned the two "January" and same thing for their values (select two column with ctrl+click and then right click "fusionate").

[image]